# Connecting to another access database in windows 365

Tags: ms-access, vba

We have upgraded from Windows 7 to windows 365.

We have a macro within an access database. The macro opens another database using the code below. However since moving across to windows 365 it doesn't like the *cn.open* line.

How do you connect to another database from within Access in windows 365?

```
 dim cn As ADODB.Connection
 set cn = New ADODB.Connection
 cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & pDBPATH & pDBNAME
```

the error message is,

> run-time error 3706: Provider cannot be found. it may not be properly installed.

Although after reading it looks like Microsoft Jet OLEDB 4.0 is not 64 bit. So is there another way?

Comment: Eh... That code will never work, since the connection is not initialized before you're trying to open it.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth sorry updated my post I missed out the line that initialises the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to connect between databases in Access.

The most usual provider for OLEDB connection is the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider:

```
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & pDBPATH & pDBNAME
```

You can view two different providers Access uses to connect to the current database, by executing the following code:

```
Debug.Print CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString 'Usual connection
Debug.Print CurrentProject.AccessConnection.ConnectionString 'Used for updateable forms
```