# Access the Data Link Properties in Access 2010 through VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to retrieve in VBA the Connection String of the SQL Server database currently connected to my Access 2010 project. The connection properties are already inserted into Info/Server/Data Link Properties (image linked). Is there anyway to retrieve this information in VBA?

Location where the connection properties are already stored:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49194982/7658533

Comment: @UnhandledException it does! Thanks a lot, I must have missed that one when doing my searching. Cheers!

Comment: @UnhandledException can you post the link to this url as answer, so I can mark it as answer? Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting to another access database in windows 365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192490/connecting-to-another-access-database-in-windows-365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question will be answered here: [Connecting to another access database in windows 365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192490/connecting-to-another-access-database-in-windows-365/49194982#49194982)

See

> Debug.Print CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString 'Usual connection

or

> Debug.Print CurrentProject.AccessConnection.ConnectionString 'Used for updateable forms